# Passing multiple properties in vuejs witch class

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a reusable components with BEM methodology in mind by using global mixins.
Here is a live example of what I'm trying to do in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/ojyym18355

As you can see, I would like to be able to pass multiple props as an array with class, so it will render `test test--one`, so far only the last class `test--one` is output.
Any idea how I can solve this problem? thank you!

Comment: please clarify your use case, i don't understand what do you want by `<p v-bind="test_one">test-one</p>
    <p v-bind="test_two">test-two</p>
    <p v-bind="[test, test_one]">test == NO - test-one == OK</p>`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't enough clear with my problem, I updated my example in the link above. If you inspect my example to view the source, you can see that in my first example it has 'test' class, my second it has 'test--one'.

Now I would like to bind both 'test' and 'test_one' so it will render both 'test' and 'test--one'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example, when you add multiple bindings this way `v-bind="[test, test_one]"`, it transforms into following bindings on the element:

```
class="test"
class="test--one"
```

Which, means that the last value overwrites `class` binding and you are left with a single value of `test--one`.

As a solution, classes can be passed the same way as multiple bindings - as an array or object. Here is an example:

[image: Edit Vue global mixins]

Note, that this is an example of more flexible usage of bindings. In order to make reusing components efficiently, initial data format of mixin's `data` property may require adjustments.

Comment: Hello, thank you for help. Is there no way to have solution without writing another computed properties? There is no solution to not overwrite my class when binding multiple props?

Comment: It would be considered a good practice to move such logic from the `template` tag. Still, you can go with one liner binding `class` directly: `:class="[test.class, test_one.class]"`

Comment: My project uses Vuetify as a framework with this article as a good practice https://alligator.io/vuejs/passing-multiple-properties/.

What I want to do is to add class to those components in order for me to write my own css. What would be a good practice to bind multiple props in my template? Like in bootstrap I would like to write `btn btn-primary`.

Comment: The way article presents passing multiple properties is the same as CodeSandbox solution in the answer. Along with binding `vuetify` props (as article suggests), you can bind `class` array as another property in bindings object. The example above shows flexibility of how props bindings can be used. Final solution depends on the input data (settings) format for components. Personally, I would created a separate computed property for classes and merge it to a computed property of bindings, along with other properties settings, acceptable by `vuetify` component's API.

Comment: In your example above, how can I write this computed function in my external mixin files?

Comment: Since mixins are merged into components, they have the same API. So simply moving `computed` block from example component into a mixin will works and will allow usage of that property inside the template. Please, see updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vj67m9wll3). If additional dynamic configuration is necessary, you can change `multipleBindings` into a `method`, that will be able to accept arguments and even more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for the updated live example. I tried with multiple properties binding but I got an error `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.` (here my CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/7j0o5n46yq)

Comment: Sorry, I can't see that error in your CodeSandbox example. But I can see that `multipleBindings` has been changed to a function, which means it should be invoked, when used inside `<template>` tag. Also, this way of binding `v-bind="[test_three, multipleBindings()]` will bring you the same issue, that initial question had: `class` will be overwritten by second binding.

Comment: Thing to reconsider: you have all `data` for bindings defined inside the mixin, but you are still trying to use both `data` and `multipleBindings` inside the component. I'd suggest to let mixin do collection of bindings and leave component as a consumer of it's output. Otherwise, data flow becomes and clear.

Comment: I have updated the example here https://codesandbox.io/s/7j0o5n46yq, can you see the error now? If I understand well, I cannot do multiple binding like this `v-bind="[test_three, multipleBindings]`? Sorry I know it's a lot request for you to answer...

Comment: I see. That is because `v-bind` accepts an array of objects, while in our case `multipleBindings` is an array itself. Simply changing return value of computed property into an object inside the mixin resolve the error. See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y215v3201j). Still, `test_three` contains `class` binding, which will be overwritten by second argument. You have to merge them, if this is the way you want to continue.

Comment: OK thank you so how do I merge them so I can have both `test_three` and `multipleBings` class? I'm still new with Vue, sorry about that...

Comment: This is very opinionated solution and it is out of scope of current question, but it gives an option to use mixin's bindings directly, or extend them with custom bindings: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y215v3201j). [Lodash-es.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) utilities are used to help keep code clean and optimized.

Comment: Almost there, thank you. Is there really any solutions for me to pass multiple binding like this `v-bind="extendMixinBindings([test_three, test_four])"`? It is important that I can pass multiple props so that I can extend `test_three && test_four`. Here's the CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/mmkp5kjjm8

Comment: Lodash [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) function can accept multiple source objects. I've updated your [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojom7yxyy6). Note, that bindings now should be passed as an array, unless you add custom type check inside `extendMixinBindings` method. Current questions are out of scope of original question and will not be helpful for other users. Please, consider posting a new question, if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time! I posted another issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081769/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export-when-using-lodash-with-nuxt and will mark this one as solved, thank you!