# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export when using lodash with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Here is my repo with live demo https://github.com/alechance/nuxt-lodash. I'm using Nuxt with Vuetify + lodash-es, when running `npm run dev` and reload my page I got a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` with `export default isArray;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imported files of `lodash-es` library are not transpiled by `babel`. To fix that, Nuxt.js provides option to manually specify files that should be transpiled via [transpile](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#transpile) option.

Add following code to `build` section of `nuxt.config.js`:

```
build: {
  transpile: [
    'lodash-es'
  ],
  // Other build options
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. However I wanted to test Vuetify `a la carte` with `babel-plugin-transform-imports` and I still got this error. I just updated the repo in github https://github.com/alechance/nuxt-lodash, I don't understand the problem...

Comment: `babel-plugin-transform-imports` overwrites `transpile` configuration. If you want to have tree-shaking, you can use latest version of nuxt with official vuetify recommendation for [a la carte](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte#importing-components). Or use [vuetify-loader](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte#vuetify-loader) that will bundle and split component's automatically. Or even use [babel-plugin-lodash](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash), as another option.

Comment: OK good, I tried something else here https://github.com/alechance/nuxt-vuetify-lodash, lodash and vuetify seem to be working, however it looks like my app is loading every vuetify components. Then I tried to overwrite vuetify styles with my own CSS, vuetify always comes after my styles. Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works. This is out of scope of current question, but from personal experience, fully featured UI libraries usually do not expect their styles being overwritten. Total cost of such overwrite, eventually, is higher than recreating necessary component's on your own. This is personal experience, not a trend.

Comment: Yes I understand, I just want to change a few CSS properties and do not want to write `!important` in my styles. It looks like my CSS is rendered in my `<head>` before the ones from vueitfy. Do you know how I can change the order in my `<head>` so that my styles come after vuetify CSS? I know it's out of scope from my initial question...