# Nuxt Error: Syntax Unexpected token export after installation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js, babel-loader

I am using Nuxt for my Vue project, It was working fine. I deleted my yarn and NPM cache due to other project issues. I re-installed the packages for my Nuxt app. The app is Universal and Uses express. Installation and Dev server is running, but when I try to visit `http://localhost:3000/`,

The error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export, shows up every time.

I know this is babel issue but I don't how to resolve this issue on Nuxt.

Nuxt Configuration:

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css',
    '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/element-ui',
    '~/plugins/vee-validate.js'
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo'
  ],
  apollo: {
    tokenName: 'yourApolloTokenName', // optional, default: apollo-token
    tokenExpires: 10, // optional, default: 7
    includeNodeModules: true, // optional, default: false (this includes graphql-tag for node_modules folder)
    authenticationType: 'Basic', // optional, default: 'Bearer'
    // optional
    errorHandler (error) {
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
    },
    // required
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        // required  
        httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4000',
        // optional
        // See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http.html#options
        httpLinkOptions: {
          credentials: 'same-origin'
        },
        // You can use `wss` for secure connection (recommended in production)
        // Use `null` to disable subscriptions
        wsEndpoint: null, // optional
        // LocalStorage token
        tokenName: 'apollo-token', // optional
        // Enable Automatic Query persisting with Apollo Engine
        persisting: false, // Optional
        // Use websockets for everything (no HTTP)
        // You need to pass a `wsEndpoint` for this to work
        websocketsOnly: false // Optional
      },
      test: {
        httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:5000',
        wsEndpoint: 'ws://localhost:5000',
        tokenName: 'apollo-token'
      },
      // alternative: user path to config which returns exact same config options
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  }
}
```

My `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My exceptional Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "Saima",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.3.92",
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.0-rc2.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.4.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with Nuxt but it looks like it's a syntax error before an export statement, have you checked for syntax errors in the `./package` directory?

Comment: @Azeame I installed a new nuxt app, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @Azeame package is actually the package.json file.

Comment: Can you make sure it's valid (package.json) ?

Comment: @BeniaminH package.json is added.

Comment: @BeniaminH package.json is valid

Comment: I tried this issue on others computer and still the same error.

Comment: It's just a guess - what if you change this: `build: { babel: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'] } }` in your nuxt config [link](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#babel)

Comment: or `presets: ['@nuxt/babel-preset-app']`

Comment: I will try this...............

Comment: @BeniaminH no luck

Comment: :/ sorry, I have no other ideas.

Comment: @BeniaminH I completely created a new nuxt app still the same issue.

Comment: @BeniaminH I am glad that you give time.

Comment: @BeniaminH are you sure this is babel issue?

Comment: could be caused by a plugin creating an issue with ssr. could you try and change nuxt.config.js like this. `plugins: [{src: '~/plugins/element-ui', ssr: false},{src: '~/plugins/vee-validate.js', ssr: false}]` and in the build section, `build: { transpile :[ '/plugins'], //leave other elements in...}`

Comment: It looks like, but I'm not 100% sure. You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081769/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export-when-using-lodash-with-nuxt)

Comment: @Andrew1325 I just checked and vee-validate with srr false create errors when you reload the page. Keep true

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just checked your issue and it happens when you use element UI with Nuxt. Update your Nuxt configuration like this(Andrew Answer):

```
plugins: [
  {src: '~/plugins/element-ui', ssr: false},
  {src: '~/plugins/vee-validate.js', ssr: true},
],
```

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I didn't test it but figured it had to be one of the two.

Comment: I tested your snippet and its okay.

Answer (score 11):

This error can show up if you're importing an ES6 module which needs to be transpiled in order to load into the UI. In that case, this is fixed by adding the module into the `transpile` key of the `build` section of `nuxt.config.js` (at time of this post, the Nuxt [transpile](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#transpile) docs are a little confusing).

For instance, if you're trying to import a module called `@stylelib` then you'd want the following in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  ...
  build: {
    ...
    transpile: ['@stylelib']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was found in my nuxt.config.js file where i had placed some extra code with a ',' at the end of that code. The code in question was at the top of the file.

The code:

```
env: {  
  strapiBaseUri: process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:1337"
},
```

My setup details are:

Nuxtjs (version as of March 20, 2020)
Apollo and Graphql
Strapi (backend)

Answer (score 0):

For me (typescript Nuxt) it was using:

```
npm run start
```

instead of:

```
npm run dev
```